# C# LINQ sub-where

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

I have object

```
   public class OrderItem
   {
      public string idProduct { get; set; }
      public int quantity { get; set; }
      public List<WarehouseItem> WarehouseInfo = new List<WarehouseItem>();
   }

   public class WarehouseItem
   {
       public string Name{ get; set; }
       public string LocnCode{ get; set; }
   }
```

and i need select items which have WarehouseInfo.LocnCode == "A1"

It is doesnt work when I use something like

```
var items = itemList.Where(x => x.WarehouseInfo.Where(y => y.LocnCode.Equals("A1")));
```

Comment: Do you want to project the order items or the warehouse items themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirements could be interpreted one of three ways, so here's three solutions:

1. Give me all `OrderItems` where ANY `WarehouseItem` has a `LocnCode` of `"A1"`:

   ```
   var items = itemList.Where(i => i.WarehouseInfo.Any(w => w.LocnCode  == "A1"));
   ```
2. Give me all `WarehouseItem`s within the `OrderItem`s that have a `LocnCode` of `"A1"`:

   ```
   var items = itemList.SelectMany(i => i.WarehouseInfo)
                       .Where(w => w.LocnCode.Equals("A1"));
   ```
3. Give me all `OrderItems` where ANY `WarehouseItem` has a `LocnCode` of `"A1"`, and filter `WarehouseInfo` to only those `WarehouseItem`s:

This can't be done in a simple Linq query because there's no way to *change* the contents of the existing objects.  You're going to have to create *new* objects with the filtered values:

```
    var items = itemList.Where(i => i.WarehouseInfo.Any(w => w.LocnCode  == "A1"))
                        .Select(i => new OrderItem
                                     {
                                         idProduct     = i.idProduct, 
                                         quantity      = i.quantity,
                                         WarehouseInfo = i.WarehouseInfo.Where(w => w.LocnCode.Equals("A1"));
                                                                        .ToList()
                                     }
                               );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var items = itemList.Where(x => x.WarehouseInfo.Any(y => y.LocnCode.Equals("A1")));
```

The `Where` takes a predicate that should return a `bool`.  `Any` will return true if at least one item in the collection returns true for the given predicate.